# Remote Watir-Webdriver IE form field not recognizing text and keys

Tags: internet-explorer, validation, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I have been using **Cucumber / Watir-Webdriver** just fine with IE.  In my tests, I go to a form field and enter data and click a save button. All actions work great.

Recently I decided to go with **Selenium Grid 2** to distribute tests across machines for performance reasons.  It worked great with FF and Chrome but I began to see a problem with IE.

**Here's the problem:**

when I use Selenium Grid 2 to drive IE remotely, when it sends keystrokes (i.e. send_keys or .set "some string of text") the text is correctly displayed in the field,  **BUT** the field validation doesn't recognize the text.

On saving the form, I will get an error saying "please enter a Description" - yet the description is there.

**This works fine if I run the test locally with watir-webdriver (and IE)**, but only has this issue when the test is being driven from Selenium Grid.

**Here's how I've set up my browser with the Grid:**

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url=>"http://[myhost]:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities=> browser_name)
where browser_name is currently set to ie.
```

**On the remote machine I set up the node with:**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-[version].jar -role node -hub [path to the above hub, ie http://[myhost]:4444/grid/register] -browser browserName="internet explorer"
```

The test code itself is pretty simple, it logs in to our internal application, then it clicks a button that presents a form. In the form it sends data to a field and clicks save.

**The test does this:**

```
Watir::Wait.until { @browser.div(:id=>"after-announcement-container").text_field(:name=>'Description').exists?}
@browser.div(:id=>"after-announcement-container").text_field(:name=>'Description').set "This is a Test"
@browser.div(:id=>'save-announcement-button').click
```

**When I run the test the Grid:**

1. sends the test to the machine
2. IE on the remote machine starts
3. IE automates through the application
4. At the form, it sends the text correctly ("This is a test")
5. IE clicks save.

At this point the form says "**Please provide a description**" (which is there and reads "This is a test.")

**I've Tried:**

1. adding wait time
2. using send_keys like :tab and :click to enter the field first before sending text.
3. I have also kept the webdriver session open and manually saving (clicking save) and I always get the error. even clicking around the app and clicking save - it still thinks the field is empty.  Once I manually type one keystroke though, it works.

**Webdriver Output:**

Webdriver does have some output, showing it's sending the text fine, and I can visually see it in the form:

```
11:06:21.296 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 7 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.
EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement@f3140943, [This is a Test]] at URL: /
session/135941c9-389d-45fa-9fed-14620a4802ca/element/7/value)
11:06:21.662 INFO - Done: /session/135941c9-389d-45fa-9fed-14620a4802ca/element/
7/value
11:06:23.192 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.Status@
4ead24d9 at URL: /status)
```

The weird part to me, is that this works if I am using watir-webdriver locally.  I only have this problem when the Grid is sending the webdriver test.

Since this works manually, the developer doesn't see this as a bug.  So I can't get much assistance to get this resolved by changing the JS.  I'm hoping there's a solution to get this to work with the Grid.

Comment: I would suggest creating a bug in Selenium bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

Comment: Thanks.  After looking into this, it appears to be a IE Webdriver issue... :(  For now I created a env value so that IE tests are run locally, and not distributed.  Just remotely using IE via selenium grid seems to be a problem.