# IE selenium webdriver without validation script running too fast

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am facing this issue in IE11

I am executing my script in FF and it runs fine

But on running script in IE it runs too fast to validate whether user entered email id is correct or not

ac.VerifyEmailTextBoxIsEditable();

function includes:
var loginCredentials = new LoginModel(_driver); //login model contain : data txtBox_email.Clear(); txtBox_email.SendKeys(loginCredentials._EmailAddressUnRegistered);

```
          ac.pwdChoice_no.Click();

          ac.btn_continue.Click();
```

before email validation is done it execute the script so though i have entered correct email it shows

"Error Login email ID field required"

And if i do it manually it is working fine.

Comment: use WAIT to make it  little slow.

Comment: i placed wait tried with explcit and implicit both

Comment: please share whole code in question.

Comment: var loginCredentials = new LoginModel(_driver);
   //login model contain : data
            txtBox_email.Clear();
            txtBox_email.SendKeys(loginCredentials._EmailAddressUnRegistered);

Comment: Edit your question to include new information, comments like yours above are very hard to read.

Comment: issue is similar to this but i am facing locally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394427/remote-watir-webdriver-ie-form-field-not-recognizing-text-and-keys

Comment: How do u know email validation is performed...if validation is accompanied by some tick mark then put a wait until that tick mark appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to slow down your test script execution, you need to configure implicit or explicit waits.  In Java there are TONS of ways that you can do this - both by extending the event listener or just plain-jane ExpectedConditions.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

I enjoy waiting for an actual element to be visible before interacting with it.  In other words, wait for element to be visible before sending keys.

e.g.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(txtBox_email));
```

After this, you can send keys and even grab the value that is set in txtBox_email... Before invoking txtBox_email.Click() (C# I"m assuming).  You COULD even wait until txtBox_email is populated if you don't care about a tight feedback loop =P.

Lastly, I recommend that you study the ExpectedConditions class/file in order to eventually construct your own explicit waits (unique cases).

Comment: Thanks let me try it out and will update if it works